Appium Testing Error: Could not start a new session. Invalid address or browser start-up failure
This is my first time using Appium and I've created a basic calculator app in Android Studio. In the same project I ave an android test package that holds my Instrumented Tests. I'm trying to just create a basic test to get everything up and running but every time I try to run the test I get this error:

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are an invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

Here is my full code as well as my libs.versions.toml as I read online it could be a compatibility issue. My Appium server is running.
package com.example.myapplication

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
import org.junit.After
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4
import org.openqa.selenium.By
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities
import java.net.URL
import org.junit.Assert.assertTrue

@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

    private lateinit var driver: AppiumDriver

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        val capabilities = DesiredCapabilities().apply {
            setCapability("platformName", "Android")
            setCapability("deviceName", "Androidphone1")
            setCapability("platformVersion", "11")
            setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2")
            setCapability("appPackage", "com.example.myapplication")
            setCapability("appActivity", "com.example.myapplication.MainActivity")
        }

        val url = URL("https://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub")
        driver = AndroidDriver(url, capabilities)
    }

    @Test
    fun testCalculatorAddition() {
        // Enter first number
        val num1Input = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[1]"))
        num1Input.sendKeys("5")

        // Enter second number
        val num2Input = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[2]"))
        num2Input.sendKeys("3")

        // Click addition button
        val addButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='+']"))
        addButton.click()

        // Click calculate button
        val calculateButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='Calculate']"))
        calculateButton.click()

        // Check result
        val resultText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, 'Result:')]"))
        assertTrue("Addition result is incorrect", resultText.text.contains("8"))
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        if (this::driver.isInitialized) {
            driver.quit()
        }
    }
}

[versions]
agp = "8.6.0"
javaClient = "8.3.0"
kotlin = "1.9.0"
coreKtx = "1.13.1"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.2.1"
espressoCore = "3.6.1"
lifecycleRuntimeKtx = "2.8.5"
activityCompose = "1.9.2"
composeBom = "2024.09.00"
testng = "7.7.1"

[libraries]
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }
java-client = { module = "io.appium:java-client", version.ref = "javaClient" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
androidx-lifecycle-runtime-ktx = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-activity-compose = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity-compose", version.ref = "activityCompose" }
androidx-compose-bom = { group = "androidx.compose", name = "compose-bom", version.ref = "composeBom" }
androidx-ui = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui" }
androidx-ui-graphics = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-graphics" }
androidx-ui-tooling = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling" }
androidx-ui-tooling-preview = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling-preview" }
androidx-ui-test-manifest = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-manifest" }
androidx-ui-test-junit4 = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-junit4" }
androidx-material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3" }
testng = { module = "org.testng:testng", version.ref = "testng" }

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }

I tried changing around my Appium Java Client versions and that didn't work. I have my server running and I don't get any output in its terminal window whenever I try to run my code. Please help.

Could you post your appium start command, if you are missing ‘--base-path=/wd/hub’, please add and try.

I am new to Appium as well but I think the issue is not with adress but rather the capabilities. capabilities were updated and you will have to use the latest capabilities.
I tried below code and it works for me in Java.
DesiredCapabilities cap_1 = new DesiredCapabilities();

cap_1.setCapability("appium:deviceName","Galaxy A15 5G");
cap_1.setCapability("platformName","Android");
cap_1.setCapability("appium:platformVersion","14");
cap_1.setCapability("appium:udid","UDID_YOur_device");
cap_1.setCapability("appium:automationName", "UiAutomator2");
cap_1.setCapability("appium:appPackage","com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator");
cap_1.setCapability("appium:appActivity","com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator.Calculator");

URL url = new URL("appium_provided_url");
driver_mb1 = new AppiumDriver(url,cap_1);

